# Is it same preprocessing method using Keras flow_from_directory and my method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This is preprocessing using ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory to train my model in Keras.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_dir = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deeplearning\ajou cat project resnet 18\data\trainset')
 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, batch_size=16, target_size=(224, 224), color_mode='rgb')

# number of classes
K = 10

input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype='float32', name='input')

#
# model architecture
#

x = conv1_layer(input_tensor)
x = conv2_layer(x)
x = conv3_layer(x)
x = conv4_layer(x)
x = conv5_layer(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output_tensor = Dense(K, activation='softmax')(x)
 
resnet = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)

resnet.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'rmsprop', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
resnet.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch = 11, epochs = 50)
```

And this is for preprocessing method I made to test my trained model with one picture.

```
target = (224, 224)
image = pilimg.open(r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\deeplearning\ajou cat project resnet 18\test\test.jpg')
image = image.resize(target)
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)
image = image/255
```

Are they the same preprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are same but if you want to apply multiple processings and to be sure about the processing methods, `ImageDataGenerator` takes `preprocessing_function` argument.
You can define a preprocessing function and give it to the generator. Then while testing you can use the same function.